# Why does the Noise Texture node in Geometry Nodes move my object? What is the fix?

Tags: geometry-nodes

When I add a Noise Texture node to the Offset input of Set Position, the object moves off its origin.

Why does this happen and what is the fix?

I remember seeing a Math (or Vector Math) node fix this in a tutorial, but I forget how.

With Noise Off:
[image]

With Noise On:
[image]

Comment: Noise texture outputs values between 0 and 1 for every position in the scene.  You are using *Set Position* to move the vertices of your object by this amount.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your wording, but I think you're expecting it to distort, but _around_ the origin point? That's because the noise texture is located in the $(0,0,0)$-to-$(1,1,1)$ space. To "center" it around the origin (so it is located in the $(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5)$-to-$(+0.5,+0.5,+0,5)$ space instead) you can `Vector Math`--Subtract: $0.5,0.5,0,5$

Comment: Hey @Kuboå thanks for this. You may submit as an answer if you like for this is it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, you're expecting it to distort, but *around* the origin point? Your geometry moves, because the base of the noise texture is situated in between the coordinates $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$. To "center" it around the origin, you can use a `Vector Math` node to *Subtract* $0.5,0.5,0,5$, which will move it to between $(−0.5,−0.5,−0.5)$ and $(+0.5,+0.5,+0.5)$ instead:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to also do this with a map range node?

Comment: @Neil I don't think so, as far as I can see